# What is the recommended and most performant API call to check if I have read permission on a dataset in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

On our Stack users by default have discoverer permissions on resources. I was surprised that this also gives users the ability to query the last_transaction_rid of the dataset (using `catalog/datasets/<rid>/reverse-transactions2/<branch>`), so this method to check if a user has access is not working.

What would be the recommended and most performant API call to check if I, with my current Foundry token, can read the actual content of a dataset? Note: I don't want to query the content, but just understand if I would have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resorted back to calling the compass/resources API and checking if `response['operations']` contains `compass:view`:

```
def get_dataset_details(api_base: str, dataset_path_or_rid: str, headers: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Returns the resource information of a dataset
    Args:
        dataset_path_or_rid: The full path or rid to the dataset

    Returns: (dict) the json response of the api

    """
    if 'ri.foundry.main.dataset' in dataset_path_or_rid:
        response = requests.get(f"{api_base}/compass/api/resources/{dataset_path_or_rid}",
                                headers=headers,
                                params={'decoration': 'path'})
    else:
        response = requests.get(f"{api_base}/compass/api/resources",
                                headers=headers,
                                params={
                                    'path': dataset_path_or_rid,
                                    'decoration': 'path'
                                })
    response.raise_for_status()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(f"Dataset {dataset_path_or_rid} not found; "
                                   f"If you are sure your dataset_path is correct, "
                                   f"check if your jwt token "
                                   f"is still valid!")
    return response.json()

details = get_dataset_details(...)

if 'compass:view' not in dataset_details['operations']:
    raise ValueError("No compass:view access to dataset")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would Data Lineage App (Monocle) work for you?

Open it `workspace/data-integration/monocle/` > Find the dataset(s) > top right dropdown ("Resource Type" -> "Permissions")

The API that powers it can be extracted by checking the Dev Tools > Network Tab if you want / need to automate it (I've done this in the past and worked well for my use case)